# Copy textbox labels and content to clipboard

Tags: copy, clipboard

I want to create a web template form for a helpdesk. Basically users will have multiple textboxes to fill out and at the bottom would be a "Copy to Clipboard" button which would copy everything in a format they can paste into the ticket system.

For example a text box might be "Phone Number: ***_*__*_***", when pasting the clipboard contents it would paste as "Phone Number: ".

It's been a long time since I've done web development, from what I understand I'll need to save the textboxes as variables and use javascript, which is alien to me, would appreciate anything that would get me pointed in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

write code to gather that data together and save to a file, display in a messagebox, etc.., Once you have that, THEN worry about copying to the clipboard.  You're just confusing things and limiting your scope by calling this a clipboard question.